# rgbdslam on fuerte

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good Morning,
I'm kind of new with ROS, and I'm trying to compile rgbdslam  on my ROS fuerte following this guide:

[here's the link](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam)

While running "rosdep install rgbdslam_freiburg" I get an error telling me "missing resource rgbdslam".
I read somewhere that rgbdslam is still not supported on fuerte and I was wondering if there is any solution to this...can someone help me? Or can someone tell me when fuerte will be supported?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45964/rgbdslam-on-fuerte/) by [Flavio P.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3393/flavio-p./) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-10-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-10-17**:
I'm guessing you skipped a step somewhere, e.g. not working in a directory in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH. Could you edit your answer to include more detail of what you exactly did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that octomap_server can not be resolved automatically by rosdep install. To manually install octomap_server execute the following command: `sudo apt-get install ros-DISTRO-octomap-mapping` (where DISTRO is your ROS distribution, i.e. fuerte). After octomap is installed, run rosdep install again to resolve the other dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [Robbiepr1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4154/robbiepr1/) with karma: 143 on 2013-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-02-20**:
Unfortunately, there seems to be no rule for ros-fuerte-octomap-mapping, to make it rosdep-able